# How to check optimization using node command-line v8-options

Tags: node.js, v8

I am running nodejs (v8 8.12.0 LTS).

I really want to check optimization about my js code.

so, I executed this command.

> node --trace-opt --trace-deopt index.js

or

> node --trace-opt --trace-deopt --trace-ic index.js

but, nothing shown.. not any comments on console.

Actually I expected like this.

[deoptimizing (DEOPT eager): begin 0xc6b3e5e7fb9  (opt #0) @1, FP to SP delta: 24, caller sp: 0x7ffe2cde6f40]
  reading input frame myFunc => node=4, args=2, height=1; inputs:
      0: 0xc6b3e5e7fb9 ; [fp - 16] 0xc6b3e5e7fb9 
  translating frame myFunc => node=4, height=0
    0x7ffe2cde6f10: [top + 0] <- 0xc6b3e5e7fb9 ;  function    0xc6b3e5e7fb9   (input #0)
[deoptimizing (eager): end 0xc6b3e5e7fb9  @1 => node=4, pc=0x30c7754496c6, caller sp=0x7ffe2cde6f40, state=NO_REGISTERS, took 0.047 ms]

but I think it's not working command with v8 options..

Why I can't get this information I expect?

this is my example code.

```
function myFunc(nb) {
    return nb + nb;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
    myFunc(i);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
    myFunc(i + '');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `myFunc` in your example is so small that 2000 invocations are not enough to trigger optimization for it. Try making it bigger, or calling it more often.